# How to override android back key in kivy?

Tags: android, python, kivy

I want to write a kivy program that could pop up a window when user hits the exit button in phone, in which users could confirm the exit action. I tried to define a on_stop function in App class, but it has no affect. How to override the back button in android so that I could do this? It seems in java I need to override the onkeydown function, so maybe I need to use pyjnius? Does kivy provide something? If not, how to use pyjnius to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: OK I will make the question more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/inclement/phutball/blob/master/main.py#L29) is an example of doing it in one of my programs. Most of it probably isn't necessary, I think you only really have to return True for keycode 27.